# monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet does not accept input after asking for seeds

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Antivirus erased monerod.exe, had to reinstall Monero, which created a new wallet. Followed help instructions to recover old wallet (in directory with monero-wallet-cli.exe, opened command line, entered monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet, able to input new wallet name, did not ask for new PW, asked for seed, but cursor just blinks, won't take any words

Comment: Have you already tried opening `monero-wallet-cli` through the PowerShell?